# Saving Multiple Charts in Excel into one PDF file

Tags: excel, pdf, charts, vba

I am using Excel 2013.  I am trying to save multiple charts in one excel workbook to a pdf file.  The charts are on different sheets that have data on it.  So, I need to select the chart on each sheet and save to one PDF file.  I would like to have one chart on one page in the pdf file.  Is there a way to do this?  I appreciate the support.

Thank you Jeannine

Answer (score 0):

Select the sheets with the charts and save as PDF.

Answer (score 0):

A VBA solution that on reflection looks a tad cumbersome, but it is customisable?  Put the code in a standard code module and replace the outputPath with yours. The approach is to compose the layout on a separate sheet and then export the sheet to .pdf.  For this example make sure you have a sheet called "Compose" in your workbook (perhaps add some code to do this).

```
 Option Explicit

Sub chartsTopdf()
Dim outSheet As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
Dim RngToCover As Range
Dim chtObj As ChartObject
Dim outputPath As String, fileStem As String
Dim chHeight As Long, chWidth As Long
Dim topM As Integer, botM As Integer, rightM As Integer
Dim n As Integer, pbRow As Integer, rwOffset As Integer
Dim chrt As String

Set outSheet = Sheets("Compose")
outputPath = "C:\Data\Barry\VBA\SO\"
fileStem = "Charts"
'these values in 'points'
topM = 60
botM = 60
rightM = 60
'these values in 'rows'
pbRow = 1
rwOffset = 8
chHeight = 12
chWidth = 5
Set RngToCover = Cells(chHeight, chWidth)
n = 0

    With ThisWorkbook
        With outSheet
            .ResetAllPageBreaks
            .ChartObjects.Delete
                With .PageSetup
                    .Orientation = xlPortrait
                    .PrintArea = ""
                    .TopMargin = topM
                    .BottomMargin = botM
                    .RightMargin = rightM
                End With
        End With

        For Each sht In .Worksheets
            If Not sht.Name = outSheet.Name Then
                'Copy Chart
                Set chtObj = sht.ChartObjects(1)
                chtObj.Copy
                    With outSheet
                        .Paste
                        n = n + 1
                        Set RngToCover = .Range(.Cells(pbRow + rwOffset, 1), .Cells(pbRow + rwOffset + chHeight, 1 + chWidth))
                        Set chtObj = .ChartObjects(n)
                        chtObj.Height = RngToCover.Height ' resize
                        chtObj.Width = RngToCover.Width   ' resize
                        chtObj.Top = RngToCover.Top       ' reposition
                        chtObj.Left = RngToCover.Left     ' reposition
                        'add hpage break
                        .HPageBreaks.Add before:=.Cells(pbRow + rwOffset + chHeight, 1 + chWidth).Offset(2, 0)

                        pbRow = .HPageBreaks(n).Location.Row
                    End With
            End If
        Next sht

    ActiveCell.Select

        'set essential page parameters
        With outSheet.PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .PrintArea = ""
            .TopMargin = topM
            .BottomMargin = botM
            .RightMargin = rightM
        End With

        'produce pdf file
        outSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            outputPath & fileStem & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True

    End With

End Sub
```

I used this [interesting article](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ResizeAndMoveAChart.html) by Jon Peltier which may also be of interest.

Comment: If it answers your Q perhaps you would 'accept' the answer by clicking the 'tick'.  This will indicate that it has been resolved.